# minikube does not download a public docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

Good day!

I am facing a strange problem. I have a standard deployment that uses a public image. But when I create it, I get the error **ImagePullBackOff**

```
$ kubectl get pods
```

result

```
api-gateway-deployment-74968fbf5c-cvqwj   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          6h23m
api-gateway-gateway-deployment-74968fbf5c-hpdxb   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          6h23m
api-gateway-gateway-deployment-74968fbf5c-rctv6   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          6h23m
```

my deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-deployment
  labels:
    app: api-gateway-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-gateway-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-gateway-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-gateway-node
        image: creatorsprodhouse/api-gateway:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I am using the docker driver, is there anything I can do wrong?

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Comment: What does `kubectl get events` show regarding those pods? It might give you the reason for the image pull failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your internet connection is slow. The timeout to pull an image is `120` seconds, so kubectl could not pull the image in under `120` seconds.

First, pull the image via `Docker`

```bash
docker image pull creatorsprodhouse/api-gateway:latest
```

Then load the downloaded image to `minikube`

```bash
minikube image load creatorsprodhouse/api-gateway:latest
```

And then everything will work because now kubectl will use the image that is stored locally.